# Add delimter to data posted to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The post data is separated by commas. I need to add a delimiter (concatenate) such as '|' to all the input fields (text, textarea, select, etc) to the post data submitted by a form, but I do not want to change the value of the fields themselves in the form.

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">

<div class"line">
<input type="text" class="sometext" name="desc" />
</div>

<div class"line">
<input type="text" class="sometext" name="desc" />
</div>

<div class"line">
<input type="text" class="sometext" name="desc" />
</div>

<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" />

</form>
```

I tried the below code, but it changes the data in the form itself

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitbutton', function(){
   $('.sometext').each(function(){
      var descVal=''
      var descVal = $('.sometext').val() + '|';
      $(this).val(descVal);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `$('.sometext').val()` you're not specifying exactly which element you want the value of. Change:

```
var descVal = $('.sometext').val() + '|';
```

To:

```
var descVal = $(this).val() + '|';
```

Alternatively you can simply use:

```
$(this).val(this.value + '|');
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitbutton', function(){
   $('.sometext').each(function(){
        $(this).val(this.value + '|');
   });
});
```

Comment: sorry, typo in the jquery. i need to concatenate '|' to all inputs from the form regardless of their name, id or class.

Comment: @Patriotec you're already looping through them using `$.each`, so that's irrelevant. I've edited my answer.

Comment: $('form.invoice :input').each(function(){$(this).val(this.value + '|');}); is closer, but it changes the html within the inputs on the page. I only want to change the data that is posted to the form's action page

Comment: figured it out. use your code but with another variable (i.e. var 't1') for each input with the same name so that doesnt change the html on the page, then send the newly concatenated string to the action page using .post [$.post('somepage.php?t1=' + t1)]. thanks for the help